# How to enforce style rules and conventions on compile time?

Tags: java

Our development team follows a set of rules when writing code. I was playing with the idea to explicitly enforce those rules on compile time. We do have settings in the IDE which show hints for many of the rules, but not all. And some errors still slip through. Apart from formatting (which we can check with Checkstyle and fail the build with maven), is it somehow possible to enforce rules like these on compile time? :

- Each Bean and Dao needs a test file with the same name + Test, for example: personDao.java -> personDaoTest.java
- Each entity (annotated with @Entity) must reside in a package ending with .entities
- It's not allowed to call any of the System.out.print* methods (those are frequently used for debugging but should never be checked into our codebase)

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Comment: not an answer, but did you try to look at SonarQube (https://www.sonarqube.org/)? Even if not advised by them, you can make the build fail if some rules are violated, and it can cover MUCH more than your requirements. A great addition to any project :)

Comment: Or you could enforce coding rules when authorizing to merge a pull request.

Comment: @Spi thank you, will be looking into SonarQube!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/). Great tool for unit testing of your architecture.

You just write a test for everything you want to enforce. E.G. Test for Entities must reside in `entities` package would look like this.

```
public class EntityTest {

    private JavaClasses classes;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        classes = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("org.my.company");
    }

    @Test
    public void classesAnnotatedAsEntitiesShouldResideInEntitiesPackage() {
        ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
            .that().areAnnotatedWith(Entity.class)
            .should().resideInAnyPackage("..entities")
            .check(this.classes);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I didn't even think about the possibility to Unit-test the architecture itself, this makes implementing the rules a breeze (especially because we don't need any extra architecture)! Thank you very much